# rudder nodes not seen by rudder server

Tags: rudder

I've configured rudder server 4.3 on debian stretch, and rudder agent 4.1 for raspberrypies and one other rudder agent 4.3 on a debian stretch machine,

no iptables rules between them. On the rudder server I can see logs about the raspberrypies names and stretch rudder agent machine,

in /var/log/rudder/apache2/access.log

But in the dashboard, no way to see the nodes. Nothing in node management/accept new nodes.

Tcpdump shows network flows on tcp 5309 from all nodes to rudder server.

On the nodes, I already configured :

/var/rudder/cfengine-community/policy_server.dat

with rudder server hostname (which can be resolved)

then

service rudder-agent start

rudder agent inventory

rudder agent run

but no way to see the nodes from rudder server ...

How can I discover the nodes from the server ?

Thank you for your help

Olivier

Answer (score 2):

Rudder 4.3 beta1 contains the https://www.rudder-project.org/redmine/issues/12083 bug which prevents the agent from running regularly like it should (and it is necessary to process the inventories. You need to execute):

```
systemctl enable rudder-agent rudder-cf-execd rudder-cf-serverd
systemctl restart rudder-agent
```

This should enable the continuous execution of the agent, and the inventories will show up in the interface (if they are correctly sent).

Answer (score 1):

You can check that inventories are received on Rudder server in /var/rudder/inventories (either in incoming / failed / received )

If they are in incoming can you run rudder agent run ? Rudder 4.3 on debian has bug that prevents automatic run of the agent https://www.rudder-project.org/redmine/issues/12083 and inventories may not be treated

If they are in failed you can see more details about what failed in webapp logs: /var/log/rudder/webapp/2018_03_03.stderrout.log

For more info about inventory workflow: https://www.rudder-project.org/doc-4.1/_inventory_workflow_from_nodes_to_root_server.html#_inventory_workflow_from_nodes_to_root_server

Rudder 4.3 is in expiremental status for now (beta1 and has quite some bugs), you may have a better experience by having a 4.2/4.1 server

Comment: Hello, thank you for your replies, I did systemctl enable rudder-agent rudder-cf-execd rudder-cf-serverd
systemctl restart rudder-agent on the debian stretch machine, but nothing changed, and had a look in /var/rudder/inventories, where I can find inventories of my nodes. It seems there is an error in the logs in the directory /var/log/rudder/webapp, where the 2018_03_04.jetty.log shows,

Comment: WARN  bootchecks-Could not authenticate in ncf API,maybe it was not initialized yet,retrying in 5seconds
ERRORcom.normation.rudder.rest.RestAuthentication-Authentication API forbids read access to Techniques for user REST Account:"Rudder system account"(rudder-system-api-account)". Do you have any idea ? Thank you

Comment: @olivier the message is not grave if it stops at some point. Else, it may indicate an apache problem (not started for ex).
Where are the inventories you see? `/var/rudder/inventories/which-subdirectories` ? If in incoming, it means that they were not processed by rudder. Could you run a  `rudder agen run -u` on the server and see if there is any problem? If they are in `failed`, something went wrong. In `received`, they should be displayed in rudder UI...